# Knockout attribute binding does not work with a custom function

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have a knockout model which has a `bar` element inside and I have a custom function `foo()` which is not in the model and is used to format data.

When I am binding the model to an html view with something like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: foo(bar), attr: { 'title': foo(bar)}"></span>
```

it works only partially: text is formatted, but attribute title is ignored (no error is risen, it is just ignored). But when I use:

```
<span data-bind="text: foo(bar), attr: { 'title': bar}"></span>
```

the title is output as a 'bar'. So basically custom functions are not working with attribute binding.

So is there a way to make my `foo(bar)` work properly?

P.S. here is a reproducible code:

**HTML view**

```
<span data-bind="foreach: listOfReports">
    <div class="10">
        <span data-bind="text: Helper.timestamp2HumanReadable(date), attr: { 'title': Helper.timestamp2Date(date)}"></span>
    </div>
</span>
```

**ViewModel**

```
function ArticlesViewModel() {
    this.listOfReports      = ko.observableArray([{'date' : 1283364108}, {'date' : 1893364108}]);
};
ko.applyBindings(new ArticlesViewModel());
```

and when I started to write my code to make it reproducible I saw that I am not returning a correct value in my function in Helper.

Sorry all of you guys for this post and for wasting your time. I hope I will never do this next time. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: So the `text` binding is working but the `title` is not? Can you create a jsfiddle because for me your code is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fdXDu/

Comment: Yes, in the first example the `text` binding is working, the `title` is ignored without an error. In the second example everything is working.

Comment: Please post your actual `foo` function and also how you have defined your `bar` (so is it a ko.observbale, or a computed or a "regular" property)? If you don't want to post your actual code just try to repro the issue in my fiddle from my privious comment and post the link here.

Comment: @nemesv my function foo. Looks more like this: `var Helper = {
    foo : function (bar){
        return bar.toUpperCase();
    }
}` But when I am posting it to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCJHp/) it rises error. I am trying to create a reproducible example (I have a lot of code and do not want to annoy everyone with a huge wall of code)

Comment: It is just how the fiddle works: you don't need the `var` before the Helper to make it global inside the fiddle. Otherwise your code still works: http://jsfiddle.net/LCJHp/1/ so your problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @nemesv sorry for wasting your time and thanks for help with Fiddle. The problem was trivial and I found it while making a reproducible example. It is written in the post. One more time thank you. This is not the first time you helped me with my journey to understand knockout. Please write your answer like the code should work fine (here is a fiddle) and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If `bar` is a `ko.observable` then all you need to do is this:

```
<span data-bind="text: foo(bar()), attr: { 'title': foo(bar())}"></span>
```

If `bar` is not a `ko.observable` then your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem, but my bar is an element in observable array and my text foo(bar) is working, just title foo(bar) is not